# ASP.NET Windows Authentication + server always getting anonymous user

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

Here's my scenario:

I have an intranet application. I want to let the network users automatically get logged into the application using the Windows Authentication features. If the user isn't into my network, I'll pop up to them a login screen.

So, I changed the authentication mode into web.config file to `Windows`. Then I'm using the `HttpContext.User.Identity` object in order to get the logged user into the network. So I ran the app into my localhost and it works great.

When I publish the application into the server, when I try to automatic log in, the `Identity` object is always empty.

So, I've tried the following steps:

1. Deny anonymous users. `<deny users="?"/>`, which not allows any anonymous users to enter in the application, but I got a problem here: when the user isn't into our network, the server pops up that default authentication window from Window Servers, not my personal login screen.
2. Let anonymous users in. If I get rid with that `<deny users="?"/>`, any user can access the page, but it **ALWAYS** goes to the login screen, even if I'm into my local network.

So, what I need is: when the user is into the local network, go straight without login. If they aren't, pop up a login screen to them.

Can someone help me to figure out what's going on?

Thank you all!

Comment: That's a common issue, you need to check your configuration according to that http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the following,

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="None" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost it. I've changed the impersonate to `true` and use only the `<deny users="?">` tag. Update your answer so I can accept it.